# Strange white outline around vertices in graphs made by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, metapost, edge

In Metapost I was able to make a graph where there's no gap between the edges and vertices:

[image]

But in Tikz there is a gap between the two:
[image]

Making a black "border" around the vertex did not help. No matter what I try there is a white outline, does anyone know how to remove the white outline completely?

Comment: if you will wiling to show, your code drawing vertex, than we will be able to help you. i suspect that you have or white border around it or have `outer sep` greater than zero ...

Comment: Just to add to @Zarko's comment: consider `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt] (A){};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1pt] (B) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,draw=white] (C) at (4,0) {};
\foreach \Y in {A,B,C}
{\foreach \X in {-0.5,-0.2,0.2,0.5}
{\draw[thick] ([xshift=\X*1cm,yshift=-5mm]\Y.south) -- (\Y);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` and then look how `A`, `B` and `C` compare.

Comment: Dear close voters, please give the OP a bit time to reply to comments and improve the question.

Comment: I find the close voting to be unusually aggressive in this case. I thought very hard about it and I figured that this was a simple enough example that it wasn't 100% obligatory to have code (though I would have still given the code if I had it... problem is that the document was not prepared by me, but by a collaborator who doesn't use stack exchange, so I didn't actually have the code... this made me question whether or not I should ask at all... but since it's a TikZ question and anyone looking at it will be able to make the graphs, I did feel asking the question would be okay in this case)

Comment: @marmot: Your solution worked, and not only did it work but it also solves the problem of my question not having a minimum-working-example. Would you like to answer it so that I can give you the points?

Comment: Hello user1271772 Glad to hear! I will only answer if @Zarko, who was first, does not want to answer.

Comment: @marmot: Zarko has provided a partial solution, and you have provided the entire code including minimum-working-example. Zarko would have to spend time typing in all the "\documentclass[tikz..." etc.  and thinking of a unique way to present it.  Unless you want Zarko to copy and past your answer. In any case, thank you for helping me with this :)

Comment: Let's just wait and see what @Zarko says. Most importantly, your problem is solved.

Comment: @user1271772, it will be fine if you will provide your code which make problems to you. simply because other member of site will be able to see what was wrong.  also than it will is simpler to wrote an answer. if you not willing to do this, i will not extend my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Zarko I'm not sure whether or not by "if you are not willing to do this I will answer", you mean to say "if you ARE willing to do this I will answer". In any case, I do NOT have the code, since this was done by a collaborator working on the paper, not me. The problem though, is exactly captured by the code given by marmot. Marmot's code is therefore enough to enter my question, if this is really necessary.

Comment: @user1271772, well, this site is not a service "we-will-do-your-task-instead-you`.

Comment: @Zarko, I also would not call this site a "service". I am sorry that you did not get a minimal-working-example from the person asking the question, but you did get one from someone else in a comment, and OP says that this is sufficient to capture the entirety of OP's original problem, so I hope you won't mind leaving it at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put these comments to an end... full credits go to Zarko, who already pointed out all the important facts.

The question is, as far as I understand it, why there can be a white boundary around shapes. The two most common reasons are

1. there is an `outer sep` greater than 0 and
2. the shape has a boundary path.

This is illustrated by the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt] (A){}; 
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1pt] (B) at (2,0) {}; 
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,draw=white] (C) at (4,0) {}; 
\foreach \Y in {A,B,C} 
{\foreach \X in {-0.5,-0.2,0.2,0.5} 
 {\draw[thick] ([xshift=\X*1cm,yshift=-5mm]\Y.south) -- (\Y);}} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

in which `B` comes with a nontrivial `outer sep` and `C` has a white boundary path. Unlike `A`, both shapes seem to have a white "halo".